# NSIS Installer: Detect if RequestExecutionLevel did not work

Tags: windows, nsis, uac

I have

```
RequestExecutionLevel admin
```

in my NSIS script.

The problem is, if Windows UAC is set to "never notify" and a normal user runs the installer, the installer attempts to proceed anyways without asking for permissions and fails with an obscure message half way through when it attempts to modify a directory user doesnt have permission to.

What I would like to do is fail fast and show a dialog right away saying "Please run as administrator".

I have tried adding the following snippit I found, but it ALWAYS fails unless the user is actually an admin (but not normal user with Admin execution level).

`UserInfo::GetAccountType
  pop $0
  ${If} $0 != "admin"
      MessageBox mb_iconstop "Administrator rights required!"
      SetErrorLevel 740 ;ERROR_ELEVATION_REQUIRED
      Quit
  ${EndIf}`

Comment: Windows version? What is the value of ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin and ConsentPromptBehaviorUser in your registry under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System?

Comment: I see what is actually happening now.  Even if the user uses Right Click -> Run as administrator, since UAC is "never notify", it will still run the program as the normal user.  The code I have is fine, but I'm going to change the error message to indicate this may be their problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a normal user with administrator execution level. When a non-admin wants to elevate they must use the credentials of a administrator and the new process runs as this administrator, not the user. This is called [Over The Shoulder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370567(v=vs.85).aspx#_msi_over_the_shoulder_gly) elevation...

Using UserInfo::GetAccountType is the correct solution.